# Having axis ticks show fully for errorbar plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a graph using Matplotlib using the following code:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.set_xlim([1,5])
axs.grid()
axs.errorbar(plot1_dataerr[1],range(len(plot1_dataerr[1])),xerr = plot1_dataerr[2], fmt = 'k o')
axs.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(len(plot1_dataerr[1])))
axs.set_yticklabels(plot1_dataerr[0])
```

The variable `plot1_dataerr` contains the labels for the data as its 0th element, the actual means as the 1st element and the half-length of the error bars as the second element. When I run this code (along with the exact data) I get the following: [image: The Actual Plot]

However as you can see some of the ticks on the y-axis are cut off, they should all start with 'vegetable based side dishes'. Does anyone know what I should change so that everything fits. I don't mind if some of the labels need to occupy 2 lines.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to run a `plt.tight_layout()` after plotting?  I find that that usually fixes my axes label problems the easiest, but sometimes it's not an option because I need consistent sizes for the axes display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to increase the left margin. For automatic adjustment, use

```
fig.tight_layout()
```

Else, start with

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.4)
```

and decrease the value until you are happy with the result.

Comment: The second one worked, the first one just caused even less text to display.

Comment: I think, even the automatic `tight_layout` should work when being placed just after setting the ticklabels. But there are reasons for "automatic" not being "best" (you're not showing the complete code here), so feel free to use the second option if it works better.